# cannot turn on relay indefinitely on an arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors, relay

I want to make a device like Knocki(https://knocki.com), which essentially is a relay control using a vibration sensor. i can detect vibrations rn but the problem is, once i knock the relay blinks on and then turns off. i understand this is a lack of programming that is causing this. could someone help me write code which makes it so that when i knock the relay is turned on indefinitely; until I knock again to turn relay off.

And yes u can probably tell that this code is copied from somewhere(https://wiki.keyestudio.com/Ks0068_keyestudio_37_in_1_Sensor_Kit_for_Arduino_Starters#Project_21:_Vibration_Sensor).I took it from the home page of the vibration sensor. the code was initially so that every time i knocked, the onboard Arduino led lit up. Also, right now the relay is blinking faintly every time i knock(Although correctly,in sync with my knocks)

```
#define SensorLED     13
#define SensorINPUT   3  //Connect the sensor to digital Pin 3 which is Interrupts 1.
unsigned char state = 0;
int Relay = 5;


void setup() 
{ 
  pinMode(SensorLED, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(SensorINPUT, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(1, blink, FALLING);// Trigger the blink function when the falling edge is detected
  }
void loop()
{  if(state!=0)
      {

        state = 0;
        digitalWrite(SensorLED,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(Relay,HIGH);
      }  
      else
        digitalWrite(SensorLED,LOW);
        digitalWrite(Relay,lOW);
} 
void blink()//Interrupts function
{  state++;
```

Comment: Please, check the voltage and current your relay needs in its datasheets. It is possible that your relay needs more power to keep on.

Comment: @RobertoFRey its a simple 5v relay. but now that u mention it my board is currently powering a 5v relay and a vibration sensor on my 3.3 v. does that make a difference??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its in your code: The (bad) example works only because there is a

```
digitalWrite(SensorLED,HIGH);
->>>   delay(500);
```

a delay for 1/2 sec to keep the led on.So as a check put an other delay after the relay line and it should go on for 1/2 sec too (so the led is lit 1 sec in total)

```
    digitalWrite(SensorLED,HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(Relay,HIGH);
   delay(500);
```

Thats just for checking -> NEXT STEP:
Get rid of the delays (see blinkwithoutdelay example in

```
Arduino->File->Examples->2.Digital -> blinkwithoutdelay
```

and introduce a second state variable e.g.

```
 bool relayStateOn = false;
```

to get an independent on/off of the relay and the led.(If thats - what I understand -what you want to do)

Comment: i want to be able to use  my hand to knock and the relay to be turned on or off. right now my knocking just stops the relay for a while and then it turns back on. i want it so that it remains off until i knock again, sort of like a switch

Comment: Yes I understood your wish. Have you changed the code like I wrote, nobody here will write the program for you -so please show what you have changed - edit your question, how you integrated the without delay and so on. And look in the docu wether your relay closes on HIGH oron LOW. Some PCB relays offer both options via integrated electronics.So look if you have the right inputs and if the program states fit the hardware connections

Answer (score 0):

If you feed your relay from the board, that is not the problem. Please, check the voltage in your relay when you try to set it on, if your voltage falls down, it means that this output to your relay does not supply the necessary current.